# How to set environment variables in Ubuntu OS using Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have been learning Puppet since two weeks and would like to automate few of our routine tasks. As a part of web application setup, first of all we have to set environment variables for JAVA, ANT etc. in the /homeuser/.bashrc file.

I have written the following manifests for it to set path and home variables and take it effect with out a reboot :

```
class bashrc {

file { "bashrc file":
    path => "/root/.bashrc",
    source  => "/mnt/bashrc",
    owner   => "root",
    group   => "root",
    mode    => "0644",
     }

exec { "root_bashrc":
    command     => "source  /root/.bashrc'",
    cwd => "/root",
    provider => 'shell',
     }

}
```

the below is the out put of  puppet run :

```
 root@liferay:/mnt# sudo puppet apply bash.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for liferay in environment production in 0.03 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 14.74 seconds
root@liferay:/mnt#
```

The .bashrc  file is not getting updated after Puppet run. Please help us how to set environment variables and should get reflected with out reboot using Puppet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only defined `bashrc` class. To execute code of the class you must instance it. The recommended way to do that is to add:

```
include bashrc
```

to some manifest. More about class instantiation [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html).

To modify content of bashrc file you use [augeas](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#augeas) resource. Here you have [guide](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/augeas.html) how to use it.

Comment: Hi Kkamilpl, thanks for your prompt answer. Now i have been able to execute the instance of my class bashrc and the content of the file has been modified accordingly but i am not able to source the file to reflect the environment variables. this is the errror : Error: source  /root/.bashrc' returned 2 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Bashrc/Exec[root_bashrc]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: source  /root/.bashrc' returned 2 instead                                          of one of [0]

Comment: Run puppet apply with -d option. Maybe it will print something useful.